# Unit hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I'm having trouble proving that $H = \{ (x_1,...,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i = 1 \}$ is closed. Although this seems to be a well-known result, I can't find a reference for the proof.

How should one approach it? Whatever approach I take, it seems I'm missing something fundamental required for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H=f^{-1}(1)$ where $f$ is the continuous function defined by $f(x_1,...,x_n)=x_1+...+x_n$.

Comment: A linear function is continuous.